# Extract data from more than 100 hyperlinks of web page

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using [this website](http://www.fieo.org/Offrings-from-Indian-Exporters.php) which has hyperlink for a number of companies. I want to extract the details of the companies.

When I click the company, there is a hyperlink "Certificate" which has the name, address, phone number, fax number, product. I am copy-pasting the data from certificate hyperlinks.

Can I automate this procedure somehow and extract the data into Excel?

i am not able to add the image. please try with above path of file. the certificate show the data on image formate.

Comment: Whenever I click such a "Certificate" link, I get a 404 error, e.g. http://www.fieo.org/certificate.php?memberfieotoken=26015

Comment: yes, i think there is server problem. but if a web page has end number of hyperlink on page, is it possible to extract data from that hyperlinks?

Comment: If you were really keen, you could definitely automate this with powershell. Powershell can then save all the info into an excel compatible format

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would find the following helpful: http://webscraper.io/ has a free chrome extension.  I haven't tried it.  I have used firefox plugins Down Them All plus Flashgot, but I have found it a little tricky.

I don't think either of these approaches would give you Excel files right away -- you'd then have to do some converting.